# Subtract dataframes with completely different row names and column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe 1 looks like this:

| windcodes | name | yield | perp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 163197.SH | shangguo comp | 2.9248 | NO |
| 154563.SH | guosheng comp | 2.886 | Yes |
| 789645.IB | guoyou comp | 3.418 | NO |

My dataframe 2 looks like this

| windcodes | CALC |
| --- | --- |
| 1202203.IB | 2.5517 |
| 1202203.IB | 2.48457 |
| 1202203.IB | 2.62296 |

and I want my result dataframe 3 to have one more new column than dataframe 1 which is to use the value in column 'yield' in dataframe 1 subtract the value in column 'CALC' in dataframe 2:
The result dataframe 3 should be looking like this

| windcodes | name | yield | perp | yield-CALC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 163197.SH | shangguo comp | 2.9248 | NO | 0.3731 |
| 154563.SH | guosheng comp | 2.886 | Yes | 0.40413 |
| 789645.IB | guoyou comp | 3.418 | NO | 0.79504 |

It would be really helpful if anyone can tell me how to do it in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case you have completely different indexes, use df2's underlying numpy array:

```
df1['yield-CALC'] = df1['yield'] - df2['yield'].values
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
df1['yield-CALC'] = df1['yield'] - df2['yield']
```

I'm assuming you don't want to join the dataframes, since the windcodes are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Do we need to join 2 dataframes from windcodes column? The windcodes are all the same in the sample data you have given in Dataframe2. Can you explain this?

If we are going to join from the windscode field. The code below will work.

```
df = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2,how='inner',on='windcodes')
df['yield-CALC'] = df['yield']-df['CALC']
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try to keep it as elaborated as possible:

> environment I have used for coding is **Jupyter Notebook**

importing our required pandas library

```
import pandas as pd
```

getting your first table data in form of lists of lists (you can also use csv,excel etc here)

```
data_1 = [["163197.SH","shangguo comp",2.9248,"NO"],\
["154563.SH","guosheng comp",2.886,"Yes"] , ["789645.IB","guoyou comp",3.418,"NO"]]
```

creating dataframe one :

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1 , columns = ["windcodes","name","yield","perp"])
df_1
```

***Output:***

[image]

getting your second table data in form of lists of lists (you can also use csv,excel etc here)

```
data_2 = [["1202203.IB",2.5517],["1202203.IB",2.48457],["1202203.IB",2.62296]]
```

creating dataframe two :

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2 , columns = ["windcodes","CALC"])
df_2
```

***Output:***

[image]

Now creating the third dataframe:

```
df_3 = df_1 # becasue first 4 columns are same as our first dataframe 
df_3
```

***Output:***

[image]

Now calculating the fourth column i.e "yield-CALC" :

```
df_3["yield-CALC"] = df_1["yield"] - df_2["CALC"] # each df_1 datapoint will be subtracted from df_2 datapoint one by one (still confused? search for "SIMD")

df_3
```

***Output:***

[image]